# EasyMock - how to set mock object to a field without setter?

Tags: java, easymock

i have a class with the field that initialized without setter using static call:

class A{

private B b = Env.getEnv().getInstance("b");

...

}

i want to test class A supplying a mock of class B.
Is it possible?
The A class is not mine and i can't use setter, reflection here also not possible.

Any help will be appreceated!

Thank you,

Yan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what `Env.getEnv(...).getInstance()` does. Can you change that to return your mock? If not, you've basically got a class which really isn't designed for testability, and you'll find it hard to inject the dependencies.

Comment: I, too, lean towards "redesign this class to be more testable."  (This seems like a perfect use case for dependency injection...)